# css height property

Tags: html, css

I have the following issue with css and was wondering whether there is a way to solve it by setting an absolute height value. The code I have is as follows,

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
html { height:100%; }
body { background: black; height:100%; }

#menud {
position:absolute;
padding:1em;
height:300px;
background-color:#eaeaea;
width:184px;
}

#menue {
position:absolute;
margin-top:300px;
padding:1em;
height:900px;
width:184px;
background-color:red;
}

#data {
position:absolute;
margin-top:0px;
margin-left: 184px;
width:630px;
height:600px;
border-left:1px solid #dedede;
border-right:1px solid #dedede;
}

#ad {
position:absolute;
padding:1em;
margin-top:0px;
margin-left:814px;
width:186px;
background-color:red;
height:800px;
}

#content {
width:1000px;
background-color:white;
height:100%;
}

#info {
margin-top:0px;
width:1000px;
}
</style>

<html>
<body>

<div id='content'>
<div id='info'>

<div id='menua'>test</div>
<div id='menub'>test</div>
<div id='data'>test</div>
<div id='ad'>test</div>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have set the height property to 100% but this does not cover the whole background white as one would expect it to. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanx.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the height to 100% means 100% of the current viewport height. If your page is longer than the browser viewport, the div is too short. Use auto height to let the height get calculated correctly for you.

Set the height of content back to auto (remove `height: 100%`):

```
#content {
width:1000px;
background-color:white;
}
```

and remove the `position: absolute` from your ad (or replace with `position: relative`), so that the ad's height is respected when calculating the parent's (`#content`'s) height:

```
#ad {
padding:1em;
margin-top:0px;
margin-left:814px;
width:186px;
background-color:red;
height:800px;
}
```

now your content is as long as you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

100% height is relative to the container. To cover the whole background, you will have to use  javascript. On page load you set the `height` to the window height.

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com), to do this: in that case

```
$("#content").css('height', $(window).height());
```

Comment: You don't need jQuery to do this and can just as easily set it with plain javascript.

Comment: Yes right. But then you will need to handle the different browsers. jQuery made it easy. :)

Comment: Without thinking about it much, I don't know what browsers would do it differently.

Comment: I had done similar thing, year back when I was not aware of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to remove paddings and margins from the body, like `body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`, for the relative-positioned container `div` to cover the whole height.